# Cannot sort by eventDate in search result webpart

Tags: 2013, search-results, sorting

I have a search result webpart (the same problem happens with a Search Query Webpart thay queries the same content) that looks for calendarevents later than today.

I searches through four calendars on a different application than the one that presents it.

This is the Query:

> path:"http://Site/A/Lists/Kalender" OR
>   path:"http://Site/B/Lists/Kalender" OR
>   path:"http://Site/C/Lists/Kalender" OR
>   path:"http://Site/D/Lists/Kalender"  (IsDocument:"True" OR
>   contentclass:"STS_ListItem") EventDate>={Today}

The Query correctly finds 6 events.

I then want to sort the by EventDate. EventDate is a Date/Time field, is queriable, searchable, retrievable, refinable and sortable and mapped to crawled property "ows_EventDate".

I've added this JSON to the sort order code in the search result webpart, so that I can easily test, whether the sorting Works:

```
[{"name":"Relevans","sorts":[]},{"name":"Event date","sorts":[{"p":"EventDate","d":0}]},{"name":"Date (oldest)","sorts":[{"p":"Write","d":0}]}]
```

When I see the results and change the sorting to "Event Date", it resorts, but doesn't do it correctly:

**Result A**
Eventdate: Tue Dec 15 10:30:00 UTC+0100 2015
Created: Mon Oct 26 15:28:20 UTC+0100 2015
Site/A/Lists/Kalender/DispForm.aspx?ID=4

**Result 2**
Eventdate: Fri Dec 4 09:00:00 UTC+0100 2015
Created: Tue Oct 13 14:37:44 UTC+0200 2015
Site/C/Lists/Kalender/DispForm.aspx?ID=1

**Result 3**
Eventdate: Fri Dec 11 15:00:00 UTC+0100 2015
Created: Tue Oct 13 15:55:23 UTC+0200 2015
Site/A/Lists/Kalender/DispForm.aspx?ID=3

If I create a new event, it'll end up at the top regardless of the date of the event.

Answer (score 2):

You think that *Event Date* column is *Date Time* but it is written as *Text* in Managed properties and you use that property for sorting.

For sorting to work properly you need link Crawled Property `ows_q_DATE_EventDate` to one of predefined *Date* Managed Properties `(Date00-Date09`)

[image: eventdate]

Go to Site Settings.

- Under Site Collection Administration click **Go to top level site settings**
- Click Search Schema
- find **Date** under Managed Properties and link Crawled Property `ows_q_DATE_EventDate`

Run full crawl.

**OR**

Go to those four lists and:

- under List Setting
- click **Advanced Settings**
- and then click on **Reindex Document Library**.
- After that you can **run incremental crawl** and this column will be picked up.

At the end you sort by that new Managed Property `Date00`.

And default Managed Property name of Event Date column isn't `EventDate` but `EventDateOWSDATE`

:)